# Julia: Set index at NTuple

Tags: julia

Let's say I have an NTuple with 4 entries of Int64 uninitiallized. How do I set the value of each index separately? 
I tried the setindex function of base but it didn't work. Any idea?

```
T = NTuple{4,Int64}
setindex(T,9,2) # set T(2) to 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant `NTuple{4, Int64}` not `Ntuple{4, Int64}`.

`NTuple` is a compact way of representing the type tuples having elements of a single type (not actual values but their types; the thing that might be confusing here is that `NTuple{4, Int64}` is also technically a value that you can bind to a variable, but this is not what you probably want to do given your question).

You can check this by looking up help on it. In your case it represents a type for a tuple of length 4 and all elements of type `Int64`. For example `(1,2,3,4)` is such a tuple. You can check it by writing `(1,2,3,4) isa NTuple{4, Int64}` which will evaluate to `true`.

Now if you ask why a tuple like `(1,2,3,4)` does not support `setindex!` the reason is that tuples are immutable in Julia, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Tuple-Types-1. This means that you have to assign a value to each field of a tuple upon its construction and it cannot be mutated.

If you want a mutable container you should probably consider using a vector instead of a tuple. For example:

```
julia> x = Vector{Int}(undef, 4)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 0
 0
 0

julia> x[2] = 9
9

julia> x
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 9
 0
 0
```

Comment: ^what they said, but if you're looking for a happy medium where you want a pre-determinied sized contained, look at [StaticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl), specifically `MVector`s